# i have write a php script no i want to get xml values in php but some values are not view in table

Tags: php, xml

friends please tell me which problem in this code. if any one know the solution then please tell me.
//friends please tell me which problem in this code. if any one know the solution then please tell me.

```
<?php
$sXml=
"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Projects_Detail>

    <Mr-Imran>
        <projectBudget>125000</projectBudget>
    <EmpNo>E100</EmpNo>
    <DeptName>IT</DeptName>
    <HourlyRate>625</HourlyRate>
    </Mr-Imran>

    <Mr-Imran>
        <projectBudget>120000</projectBudget>
    <EmpNo>E101</EmpNo>
    <DeptName>Database</DeptName>
    <HourlyRate>500</HourlyRate>
    </Mr-Imran>

    <Mr-Imran>
        <projectBudget>135000</projectBudget>
    <EmpNo>E102</EmpNo>
    <DeptName>IT</DeptName>
    <HourlyRate>550</HourlyRate>
    </Mr-Imran>

    <Mr-Imran>
        <projectBudget>115000</projectBudget>
    <EmpNo>E103</EmpNo>
    <DeptName>Testing</DeptName>
    <HourlyRate>400</HourlyRate>
    </Mr-Imran>

    <Mr-Imran>
        <projectBudget>150000</projectBudget>
    <EmpNo>E110</EmpNo>
    <DeptName>Database</DeptName>
    <HourlyRate>375</HourlyRate>
    </Mr-Imran>

    <Mr-Imran>
        <projectBudget>140000</projectBudget>
    <EmpNo>E112</EmpNo>
    <DeptName>Testing</DeptName>
    <HourlyRate>425</HourlyRate>
    </Mr-Imran>

</Projects_Detail>
";

$oXML = simplexml_load_string($sXml);  
 if (!$oXML) {  
      die('xml format not valid or simplexml module missing.');  
 }  

 // assuming running the root  
 $oXmlRoot = $oXML;
 // or can be [$oXML->food]  

 //echo '<pre>'; print_r( $oXmlRoot ); echo '</pre>';  
 echo xmlToHtmlTable($oXmlRoot);  


 function xmlToHtmlTable($p_oXmlRoot) {  
      $bIsHeaderProceessed = false;  

      $sTHead = '';  
      $sTBody = '';       
      foreach ($p_oXmlRoot as $oNode) {  
           $sTBody .= '<tr>';  
           foreach ($oNode as $sName => $oValue){  
                if (!$bIsHeaderProceessed) {  
                     $sTHead .= "<th>{$sName}</th>";  
                }  
                $sValue = (string)$oValue;  
                $sTBody .= "<td>{$sValue}</td>";                 
           }  
           $bIsHeaderProceessed = true;  
           $sTBody .= '</tr>';  
      }  

      $sHTML = "<table border=1>  
                     <thead><tr>{$sTHead}</tr></thead>  
                     <tbody>{$sTBody}</tbody>  
                </table>";  
      return $sHTML;  
 }  ?>
```

the output of above code is this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLubg.png)

but i want to get this code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L09Tt.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the start of your outer foreach loop, this can give you the project managers name (assuming it's just the name of the enclosing element).  So then add this in the same way your doing it with your other columns...

```
foreach ($p_oXmlRoot as $projectManager=>$oNode) {   // Include manager as key
    $sTBody .= '<tr>';
    // Add manager header
    if (!$bIsHeaderProceessed) {
        $sTHead .= "<th>ProjectManager</th>";
    }
    // Add the actual value into the table
    $sTBody .= "<td>{$projectManager}</td>";
    foreach ($oNode as $sName => $oValue){
```